# Branch.io links missing analytics parameters (campaign, channel, feature, etc.)

Tags: branch.io

I created a Branch link and left all the analytics parameters empty (i.e. I did not specify campaign, channel, feature, etc.). On my website, I then use that link and append parameters as necessary:

```
http://example.com/XXXXXXXX?~campaign=mycampaign&~feature=myfeature&~stage=mystage&~tags=tag1,tag2&matchType=m&network=n&placement=1&adposition=1&device=d&url=some-url
```

Up until recently, the Branch Web SDK provided me with all these parameters. Now, ~campaign and the rest of these params are no longer in the data_parsed object that's returned. What happened?? Why does data_parsed not have these?

Side note: The ~referring_link value returned by Branch is correct. It shows the full link as specified above.

Comment: Alex from Branch here: sorry we missed this question! I do see the same issue and it looks like a bug on our end. We are investigating

Answer (score 0):

The five default link parameters (Campaign, Feature, Channel, Stage, and Tags) cannot be overwritten on existing links by appending query parameters. This helps prevent analytics information on a link from being altered after the link has been shared (with an ad network, for example).

This will work for new links, however, which you can create by appending query parameters to your default link domain. If your default link domain was  "example.app.link," for example, tapping on the following link would cause a new Branch link created with channel, feature, and campaign set:

```
https://example.app.link?channel=facebook&feature=sharing&campaign=winter
```

So you are basically doing this correctly, but you need to append your query parameters to the default link domain and not an already-existing link.